# Recursive method with incorrect return value

Tags: java, recursion, methods

This recursive method seems to be adding to sum. For some reason when it comes to returning the sum value, sum is equal to 4, not 10, the value it should be. Why is sum not equal to 10? I am just testing the method to see if it works, the array will change.

```
public class TestMeanVal {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] intArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        System.out.println(meanRec(intArray, intArray.length-1, 0));
    }



    static double meanRec(int[] array, int b, int g){
        int sum = g;
        if (c.length == 1){
            return c[0]/1.0;
        }else if(b >= 0){
            sum += c[b];
            b--;
            meanRec(c,b, sum);
        }
        return sum/c.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `meanRec` but ignoring the return value. Did you mean to?

Comment: (Aside from anything else, it would help if you'd format your source in a more conventional form...)

Comment: No I would like to get sum to add up to 10, and then return that value divided by the length of the array. but it is only taking on value 4.

Comment: Your base condition should be based on `b`, and not `c.length`.

Comment: Well what do you expect the recursive call to do? It's not changing the values within `c`, and it won't change any of your local variables... so what's the point?

Comment: I expected it to add the value of sum each iteration of meanRec, and then return the mean of sum.

Comment: @Dave When you pass the current `sum` value to another method invocation, any changes there is not reflected at caller end. So, when the recursion starts rolling back, at the end, the `sum` will be the `0`, and you return `0 / c.length`.

Comment: @Dave Write each method invocation in that recursion on paper with the argument you're passing. It might become more clear.

Comment: Why don't the variables have meaningful names? Is this method intentionally obfuscated?

Comment: I have more code to add to this. My program is not fully complete. Thanks for bringing that back to my attention though. intentionally obfuscated? no.

Comment: At this point: System.out.println(meanRec(intArray, b.length-1, 0)); what's the value of b. I don't see it being defined anywhere. The same is true in the meanRec method. What is c? I don't see it being defined anywhere. Did you mean array instead?

Comment: That is because I edited the code. b should be replaced by intArray.length-1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to

```
 return meanRec(c, b, sum);
```

otherwise it'll recurse, but always return `sum/c.length` of the first invocation.